# Two versions of app built from library resulting in "complete action with"

Tags: android, android-intent

I've extracted an existing application out into a library project so multiple targets can be built. The application is wired together using action names rather than explicit class names. Each target obviously has its own AndroidManifest.xml files where the action names are mapped to the class names.

Unfortunately, when there are two of these built targets on the same device, performing an action means that the user is prompted whether to complete the action with App A or App B.

How can I stop this from happening? I've tried setting the activity definitions exported attribute to false. This doesn't seem to help.

I guess I could qualify the action android:name attribute with a package prefix, but this doesn't feel right. Surely there's a way of limiting it so that only actions defined within the current application are resolved, or rather, actions of a given name aren't exposed outside of the app?

```
    <activity android:exported="false"
         android:name="uk.myco.activities.EditChildFieldsActivity" 
         android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="EditChildFields" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: you could add a system in your app to query intents and take automatically the one that matches the current package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above comment, in my case adding

```
intent.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())
```

Has had the desired effect.